# Examples of trustworthy ripple paper wallets?

Tags: wallet, ripple, paper-wallet, trust

Which are examples of trustworthy ripple paper wallets? I've been reading on the internet and I have found several websites for generating ripple paper wallets: ripply.eu, bithomp.com, gatehub, ripplepaperwallet.com, etc. But I'm not sure which sites can be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like https://bithomp.com/paperwallet/ seems to be safe, 
but if you're really worried about generating public & private keys online, I would recommend you to download the source code
https://github.com/OctillionSA/ripple-paper-wallet 
and run it in an offline computer

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any website while connected to the internet.

1) Save this website(CTRL + S): http://ripplepaperwallet.com/

2) Open saved the website in a secure environment and then generate your wallet.

You can find the steps in detail here: h[ttps://www.reddit.com/r/Ripple/comments/6f4juz/psa_how_to_make_a_paper_wallet/?st=jcal6r88&sh=32e45553](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ripple/comments/6f4juz/psa_how_to_make_a_paper_wallet/?st=jcal6r88&sh=32e45553)